# Separating strings from an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have two arrays of pointers, that is,

```
char *a[3]= {"man","dog","cat"};
char *b[3]= {"job","rain","sleep"};
```

I want to separate the three strings of both above into three different characters arrays and then I want to concatenate the string from `*b[]` to the end of string from `*a[]`.

How can I accomplish this? I don't want to print the separated strings.

Comment: This question is off topic on Programmers. It would best be asked on Stack Overflow, however, the question doesn't meet their minimum requirements. Please read the Stack Overflow question checklist and [edit] your question to make it suitable for migration.

Comment: There is a need to provide a new array because expansion of the array can not be.

Comment: "*... I want to separate the three strings of both above ...*" there are **six** strings.

Comment: For one thing, it is illegal to use `char *` to point to string literals. You need `const char *`.

Comment: @Siyuan Ren: It is not _illegal to use `char *` to point to string literals._ Read the C Standard: **For character string literals, the array elements have type `char`**… **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you want the following

```
char s[3][10];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
   strcpy( s[i], a[i] );
   strcat( s[i], " " );
   strcat( s[i], b[i] );
}
```